what are the different parts of a complete recitation of the Vishnusahasranama?
I know there are at least three parts - the Dhyana Shloka, the main Sahasranama and the phalastuti.
(1) Do all communities start with the Shuklambaradharam verse?
(2) Do only Srivaishnavites add the Vishwaksena stuti after that?
(3) Which parts are in the version in the Mahabharata?
